# How to fix a problem like this in NDSolve?

Tags: differential-equations

I am a beginner on Mathematica. Now I am trying to solve second-order PDEs using NDSolve. But I encountered the following error.  Could anyone help me find out the mistake I made? 
Thank you in advance!
[image: PDEs and boundary conditions]
[image: nb code]

```
    sol = NDSolve [{Derivative[1, 0, 0][th][x, τh, 0] == 
    ntuh*(twh[x, τh, 0] - th[x, τh, 0]), 
   Derivative[1, 0, 0][tc][x, 0, τc] == 
    ntuc*(tc[x, 0, τc] - twc[x, 0, τc]), 
   Derivative[0, 1, 0][twh][x, τh, 0] == 
    ntuh/crh*(th[x, τh, 0] - twh[x, τh, 0]) + λh/
       crh*Derivative[2, 0, 0][twh][x, τh, 0], 
   Derivative[0, 0, 1][twc][x, 0, τc] == 
    ntuc/crc*(tc[x, 0, τc] - twc[x, 0, τc]) + λc/
       crc*Derivative[2, 0, 0][twc][x, 0, τc], 
   th[0, τh, 0] == 1, tc[1, 0, τc] == 0, 
   twh[x, 1, 0] == twc[x, 0, 0], twh[x, 0, 0] == twc[x, 0, 1], 
   Derivative[1, 0, 0][twh][0, τh, 0] == 0, 
   Derivative[1, 0, 0][twh][1, τh, 0] == 0, 
   Derivative[1, 0, 0][twc][0, 0, τc] == 0, 
   Derivative[1, 0, 0][twc][1, 0, τc] == 0}, {th[x, τh], 
   twh[x, τh], tc[x, τc], twc[x, τc]}, {x, 0, 
   1}, {τh, 0, 1}, {τc, 0, 1}]
sol /. {ntuh -> 15, ntuc -> 12, λh -> 5, λc -> 5, 
  crh -> 2, crc -> 2}
```

Comment: People here generally like users to post code as Mathematica code instead of images or TeX, so they can copy-paste it. It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you.  You may find this [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: Thank you for your remind.it's my first time to ask a question here. I will figure out how to add the code.

Comment: Welcome! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Your equations involve dependent quantities in three variables, for instance, `twh[x, τh, 0]`, but you are solving for the same quantities with only two variables, for instance, `twh[x, τh]`.  `NDSolve` cannot handle this inconsistency.